# How to set two JScrollPanes in different classes with same JPanel content

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I'm working on a GUI where sensors need to be added to two `JScrollPanes` in two different classes. There is a UIManager class which sends the `ArrayList` of the sensors currently connected to the UI class, which then sets these sensors inside a `JPanel` which is then set as the viewport for the two JScrollPanes:

**From the UIManager class**

```
private static void updateSensorsConnectedSmallEntries() {
    UserInterface.setSensorEntriesSmall(sensorEntriesSmall);
}
```

**Inside the UserInterface class**

```
    public static void setSensorEntriesSmall(ArrayList<SensorEntrySmall> sesList) {
        setSensorEntriesSmall(tabDataLogging.getConnectedSensorsScrollList(), sesList);
        setSensorEntriesSmall(tabLiveChart.getConnectedSensorsScrollList(), sesList);
    }

    private static void setSensorEntriesSmall(JScrollPane pane, ArrayList<SensorEntrySmall> sesList) {
        javax.swing.JPanel scrollList = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        scrollList.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        pane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        javax.swing.GroupLayout paneLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(scrollList);
        scrollList.setLayout(paneLayout);

        GroupLayout.ParallelGroup hor = paneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING);
        GroupLayout.ParallelGroup ver = paneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING);
        GroupLayout.SequentialGroup horSeq = paneLayout.createSequentialGroup();
        GroupLayout.SequentialGroup verSeq = paneLayout.createSequentialGroup();
        GroupLayout.ParallelGroup horSeqPlaceHolder = paneLayout.createParallelGroup();

        horSeq.addContainerGap();
        verSeq.addContainerGap();
        for (SensorEntrySmall ses : sesList) {
            horSeqPlaceHolder.addComponent(ses.getSensorEntrySmall());
            verSeq.addComponent(ses.getSensorEntrySmall(), javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 
                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE);
            verSeq.addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED);
        }
        horSeq.addGroup(horSeqPlaceHolder);
        horSeq.addContainerGap();
        verSeq.addContainerGap();

        hor.addGroup(horSeq);
        paneLayout.setHorizontalGroup(hor);
        ver.addGroup(verSeq);
        paneLayout.setVerticalGroup(ver);

        pane.setViewportView(scrollList);
    }
```

It seems like the problem is in the order of assigning the list to the different tabs. If I assign them first to `tabDataLogging` and then to `tabLiveChart`, the sensors are only displayed in `tabLiveChart` and vice versa.

I would like the sensors to be displayed in both of the tabs. Anyone has any suggestions on what is going wrong here?

Comment: You cannot do it because Swing has component tree but not a graph. So when you add a component to a container, it will be removed from the previous container.

Comment: *"set two JScrollPanes in different classes with same JPanel content"* .. Why?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I want to do this in order to be able to select sensors from within different tabs

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy And there is no way we can clone this list for example?

Comment: If the element is common to both, put it *outside* the tabbed pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> where sensors need to be added to two JScrollPanes in two different classes.

Swing components can only have a single parent component so you can't share the panel.

However, you can share the data. Most Swing component have a `Model`. The model can be shared.

So for example if your sensors are display in a JTable, you can share the TableModel. You would need to create two JTables, but the same model can be added to each table.